# Could not find function "color.palette"

Tags: r, plot

I am using the following function to make a plot in R.

```
plot_contact <- function(mat, zlim=NULL, mode=c('square','upper','lower'), title='', widths=c(1,4), heights=widths, useRaster=T, restore.par=T, image.only=F, value=F,
         color.palette="WhBlRdYl", under.color=color.palette(101)[1], over.color=**color.palette**(101)[101], na.color=under.color, cex=0.5, ...)
```

I have imported ggplot2 and viridis. But I got the following error. May I ask for the solutions? Thanks!

> plot_contact(balanced_X_50000_600)

> Error in color.palette(101) : could not find function "color.palette"

Answer (score 1):

Function is called `palette.colors` and not `color.palette` in package `grDevices`